# which method is used to get real notification?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I want to generate and display notification while user submit some request.
notification displayed when user click on button.
i found NSnotificationcenter but i don't know how to use it.
can anyone send me stackoverflow or other site link.

Comment: NSNotificationCenter refers to internal messaging within the app (Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html). I don't believe that is what you are after. Maybe you could describe your problem a little better? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: and some code if possible just to check out what you are looking at??

Comment: Perhaps you want UIAlertViewController ?

Comment: Thanks all for reply..  i want to notification when user submitted their request by clicking button..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how a UIAlertViewController work here is a sample code
it will show a hello world message on button tap

```
@IBAction func showMessage() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "welcome to my first app", message: "hELLO WORLD", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler:nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

If you want to show a notification in notification centre.
 You can find excellent tutorial on Local Notifications in iOS 8 [here](http://www.appcoda.com/local-notifications-ios8/)

Comment: Thanks for answer..  i want same thing like your shared link..  i tried their project but error occured.  @tk1505

Comment: it would be great if you accept this answer.. and what error does it shows.